# Need help with a PHP proxy script

Tags: php, proxy, mode

I’m currently working on a small web app that allows people to search for music album covers. However, I’m having a problem getting my PHP proxy to work. Right now I’m using a simple PHP proxy script to grab the HTML from Google’s image result page, and parse it to find the first image result (I can’t use the image search API because it doesn’t offer the parameters that I need to use). I know that the PHP script works in some way, because I’ve used it to grab XML data across domains, so I also assume that since I’m trying to grab HTML that’s what’s causing the error.

So anyway, here is the site where you can see it: http://www.5byfive.net/beta/index.html

Just type something into the textbox, and it will come up with the error that’s returned (I’ve placed the HTML into a file so you can see what it actually looks like here: http://www.5byfive.net/beta/error.html ).

Now, I’ve tried searching for info on the web, but unfortunately I basically know nothing about PHP, so I really don’t know how to fix it, and was wondering if anyone here could lend any info or help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youll have to turn off safe mode in you php.ini, it shouldnt be used anyway.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

as an aside the [last.fm webservice](http://www.last.fm/api) might be a better way to get the album art

Comment: Yeah, after doing some more searching online I came across this as well. However, I have two problems- one, I can't seem to find a php.ini file on my server, and two, if I can find it, I don't know how to edit it to turn off safe mode. Could anyone provide some additional info or links? Thanks very much!